# Using lapply in R when there isn't a function?

Tags: r, lapply, performanceanalytics

I'm pulling ETF data from Yahoo for 15 symbols and am about to write the same lines of code 15 times. I've read up on `lapply` but am failing to grasp it in this context.

After loading my `getSymbols` file, I have started the code for the first two symbols below, but will have copy and paste, then change the symbol, 15 times. I know there has to be a way to do these steps with `lapply` or something similar...

```
library(quantmod)
library(tseries)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(xts)
library(timeSeries)
library(TTR)

#load asset class symbols and data
loadSymbolLookup(file="assetclassymbols.rda")
getSymbols(c("ACWI","ITOT","IJR","EFA","EEM","AGG","MUB","TIP","TLH","TLT","HYG","EMB","IYR","GSG","GLD"))

#pull adjusted close value for a specific time period
ACWI.adj=Ad(ACWI)['2015-12-31::2016']
AGG.adj=Ad(AGG)['2015-12-31::2016']
#REPEAT FOR EACH SYMBOL

#calculate returns for the specific time period and remove prior-period "NA" row
ACWI.return=Return.calculate(ACWI.adj)
AGG.return=Return.calculate(AGG.adj)
ACWI.return=ACWI.return[-c(1)]
AGG.return=AGG.return[-c(1)]
#REPEAT FOR EACH SYMBOL

#merge asset class return streams to a single dataset
asset.returns=(merge(ACWI.return,AGG.return)) #...CONT. MERGING ALL SYMBOLS.return
colnames(asset.returns)=c("ACWI","AGG") #...CONT. LIST OF ALL SYMBOLS
```

My goal is to finish with a data set containing all the symbols as column headers, and calculated returns in each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allowed to define an anonymous function in the `FUN` argument of `lapply`, *a la*

```
syms <- c("ACWI","ITOT","IJR","EFA","EEM","AGG","MUB",
          "TIP","TLH","TLT","HYG","EMB","IYR","GSG","GLD")


lapply(syms, function(s) 
  Return.calculate(Ad(getSymbols(s, auto.assign = FALSE)
                      )['2015-12-31::2016'])[-1L])
```

Comment: I get this error whenever I try to use lapply to find the Ad (Adjusted) price column:  Error in Ad(s) : 
  subscript out of bounds: no column name containing "Adjusted"

Comment: You are correct that Ad(ACWI) works. But fails with the quotes, and fails with as.name.

Comment: @KennethK. see update. I forgot that `quantmod` is such an odd package; use the `auto.assign` option to make it behave more like a normal package (so that we can use `var_name <- getSymbols("IJR")` to assign the `xts` object to `var_name` instead of creating the variable `IJR` in the environment, the current default, which is almost impossible to word with programmatically). An alternative would be to run `Ad(get(getSymbols(s)))` but this will clutter your namespace.

Comment: Would not have figured that out. Thank you!